# how can i fix this error of gradle task assembleDebug

Tags: android, gradle

[gradle assembleDebug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaxTn.png)

Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\taxe booking app\rider_app\android\build.gradle' line: 32
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_52wuvgl4g386ua3yph5fg2j88$_run_closure4@10214f72] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 24s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You need to show your build.gradle for understanding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.